# Bash commands in python

Tags: python, subprocess

I am running a code in python which calculates the count of the files present in a directory`

```
hadoop fs -count /user/a909983/sample_data/ | awk '{print $2}'
```

This successfully returns **0** in the linux command line as the dir is **empty**.However when I run this in python script it returns **1**.The line of code in python is:

```
directoryEmptyStatusCommand = subprocess.call(
["hadoop", "fs", "-count", "/user/a909983/sample_data/", "|", "awk '{print $2}'"])
```

How can I correct this? or what am I missing ?. I have also tried using Popen, but the result is the same.

Comment: If you want to use the pipe function `|` of the shell, you need to run with `shell=True` as option. In that case you should use a string, rather than a list for the command. However, it would be better to split this command in two subprocesses, for `hadoop` and `awk` respectively and then pipe the data through Python.

Comment: @tarun , please look at the given answer below if helps you then accept as an answer so it can be removed from the un-accepted ans queue.

Comment: @pygo It would be even better if you just remove your answer, since it is a duplicate anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `subprocess.Popen` and  don't use the  pipe `|` because it requires `shell=True` which security risk. So, use the `subprocess.PIPE` and use that with `subprocess.check_output` without pipe thats the correct method.

So, you can try something like:

```
command = subprocess.Popen(("hadoop", "fs", "-count", "/user/a909983/sample_data/") , stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
output = subprocess.check_output(("awk '{print $2}'"), stdin=command.stdout)
```

In Case You want to try Shell commands by enabling `shell=True`:

```
cmd = "hadoop fs -count /user/a909983/sample_data/ | awk '{print $2}'"
command = subprocess.Popen(cmd,shell=True,stdout=subprocess.PIPE,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
output = command.communicate()[0]
print(output)
```

Comment: If the filename comes from a variable (which it probably does!), just setting `shell=True` isn't great practice without moving that variable out-of-band from content parsed as code.

Comment: Consider `subprocess.Popen(['''hadoop fs -count "$1" | awk '{print $2}' ''', '_', '/user/a909983/sample_data/'], shell=True)`, keeping your data -- the filename -- out-of-band from your code.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy,  agreed `shell=True`  indeed not recommended at all as it open up a security hole and makes a program vulnerable to shell injection, as a security expert you know better it ;-)

Comment: Well -- point I'm making is that one *can* use `shell=True` safely, if the string passed as the first element of `cmd` is a constant that was carefully audited by a human, and all elements that could vary are kept out-of-band (and there hasn't been any meddling with environment variables). But yes, avoiding it altogether is indeed the best approach. :)